Intuitively, why is the quantity of kinetic energy conserved in a 1-dimensional elastic collision of rigid bodies?
Two blocks of masses and velocities $(m_1, \textbf{v}_{1,\:i})$ and $(m_2, \textbf{0})$ composed of identical material move towards each other on a frictionless plane in vacuum.

They collide. It is always observed that the quantity of motion respective to direction is conserved, such that $$ m_1 \cdot \textbf{v}_{1,\:i} = m_1 \cdot \textbf{v}_{1,\:f} + m_2 \cdot \textbf{v}_{2,\:f}.$$ Put a better way, the amount of mass going in any direction before and after the collision stays the same. We call the quantity momentum. This is quite palatable.
Experimentally, it is also observed that as more and more "elastic" materials, like steel, are used for the composition of the two blocks, a certain quantity approaches conservation, such that $$m_1 \cdot ||\textbf{v}_{1,\:i}||^2 = m_1 \cdot ||\textbf{v}_{1,\:f}||^2 + m_2 \cdot ||\textbf{v}_{2,\:f}||^2.$$
Firstly, I notice that this quantity is scalar, rather than vector, as the quantity of motion is. The only practical difference between is that we square the velocity. And yet, experimentally, the data tend towards this conservation equation. We call the quantity kinetic energy.
Usually, explanations point to black-box theorems and formulas that aren't helpful in terms of intuition, use circular reasoning, or create elaborate setups that, although helpful in mathematically understanding the conservation, are also not intuitive to me. So, intuitively, why is the quantity of $\frac{1}{2}m \cdot ||\textbf{v}||^2$ conserved in elastic collisions?

I don’t think you are asking a question that you really want to ask. The literal answer to the question “why is KE conserved in an elastic collision” is simply that that is how elastic collisions are defined. It is like asking “why is a red truck red”. Maybe you want to ask something more like “what other characteristics of a material or structure lead to elastic collisions”, or maybe just “why is velocity squared in KE”, or maybe “why isn’t KE a vector”, or maybe “why is energy conserved”. I am unsure what you want, but pretty sure you don’t want what you asked

@Dale I grant you that the question could be more focused, but I believe there are sufficient clues. The question presents an apparent contrast. The expression for momentum has unit of mass and unit of velocity both in linear form.  $$ m_1 \cdot \textbf{v}{1,:i} + m_2 \cdot \textbf{v}{2,:i}= m_1 \cdot \textbf{v}{1,:f} + m_2 \cdot \textbf{v}{2,:f} $$ Not only is momentum conserved in one inertial coordinate system; the conservation obtains for any inertial coord. syst.: galilean relativity. It is surprising that quadratic $mv^2$ also has: conservation and galilean relativity obtain

Linear momentum is conserved in all collisions. "Elastic collisions" is the name we give to the subset of all collisions in which kinetic energy is also conserved.

I voted to close the question due to the reasoning given by Dale and others. Another analogy is "why are even numbers divisible by 2?"


So, intuitively, why is kinetic energy conserved in elastic
collisions?

Because purely elastic collisions only involve conversions between mechanical kinetic and elastic potential energy without the loss of energy in the form of heat, light, sound, etc.. An example is a collision between ideal springs.
Hope this helps.

I have updated my question to express myself better (very last line). I should've asked why the quantity is conserved, rather than why "kinetic energy" is conserved.

This implicitly moves the question to: "why is energy conserved"?

@Makemake but your update still refers to kinetic energy by equation (??)

@Makemake If you're just asking why is energy conserved in general, that's a very different question, and it makes your focus on elastic collisions unwarranted. Energy is always conserved, regardless of the collision type.

@Amit total energy is conserved. Please take note that I referred to total mechanical energy in my answer. Total mechanical energy is not conserved if either external work is done on the system or internal dissipative work is done. The latter is the case for inelastic collisions

@BobD Of course, I was replying specifically to OP's remark here above that: "This implicitly moves the question to: "why is energy conserved"?" -- although if you mean to say that you think he still means only mechanical energy, then he needs to be clear on that, too.

@Amit Sorry. I thought your comment was directed to me

The definition of elastic collision is one where kinetic energy is conserved, but
that is not the intuitive answer you are asking for.
The blocks approach one another until they become very close, $M_1$ at $x_1$, $M_2$ at $x_1 + \Delta$,
and exert force on one another for a short period of time.
Then, when $M_1$ is at $x_2$, and $M_2$ is at $x_2 + \Delta$, the force stops.
The force is caused by them being less than $\Delta$ apart.
Notice that each block has traveled the same exact distance during the collision period, and that
at each instant, $\vec{F}_{1,2} =-\vec{F}_{2,1}$. If the force in question was constant $F$ during this
collision time period, then the energy leaving $M_1$ would be force times distance $F (x2 - x1)$, and
the energy gained by $M_2$ also would be $F (x2 - x1)$, resulting in conserved energy. The integral
of $\int_0^{v_x}{F_x dx}$ works out to $mv_x^2/2$ .
The force during the collision is unlikely to be constant, but if we modeled the force as a spring
at distances less than $\Delta$, we again find that the integral of the energy lost by $M_1$
equals the energy gained by $M_2$. We see the spring absorb energy as the blocks compress it,
and see the spring transfer energy out as the blocks separate. A 'perfect' spring would release all
its energy to its compressors.
Actually, both blocks act as deforming springs, with different spring constants.
